# Android Coroutine doesn't finish

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a code where I am lazily updating the UI using kotlin couroutines.

When I am putting some code inside `GlobalScope.async` only the first few lines are executed and the rest of the code doesn't

```
class MyFragment : Fragment(), CoroutineScope {

    private lateinit var masterJob: Job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + masterJob

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
           GlobalScope.async(coroutineContext) {
            api.fetchOrders()
            configureOrders(view!!)

            // Some code here ... 
        }
   }
```

For example in the above code the code after the comment doesn't get executed. And if I swap the code above the comment with the one above it then it doesn't get executed.

What am i missing ?

Comment: You are not awaiting the `Deffered` returned from `async`. I'm not sure but it may get  canceled after the end of `onViewCreated`.

Also, have you checked for unhandled exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

When you have an async method that returns something, is async and the problem is that only the first lines of the method are executed, is because you are not waiting the method to finish with the key word await.

Something needs the value returned from the function and forces the function to end, unless you use await, then it must wait the function to end.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not right because your coroutines context is running on the main thread with that `Dispatchers.Main` keyword on the coroutine context initialization . If you want to perform API calls please change to `Dispatchers.IO` .

I assume `api.fetchOrders()` can't be run on the Main thread . Plus you need to await that response with the keyword `.await()` :

`val yourData = api.fetchOrders().await()` which will return what is inside your `Deferred` type . For example if it is an `Deferred<ArrayList>` it returns the ArrayList after you call the `await()` method .

**Note** .

If you call that await() on that coroutine context I believe you should have an error like `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was, the code was working but it was causing an exception which was not visible in the stack trace (not sure why).

When I changed `GlobalScope.async` to `GlobalScope.launch` it started working

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. Your fragment is a scope but you still use GlobalScope. `Dispatchers.Main + masterJob` is completely ignored
2. If you'd use your fragmentScope, depending on the implementation of `api.fetchOrders`, your app could crash because you are still on the main thread
3. It appears you are not interested in the result, so don't use a `Deferred`
4. If `async` is what you want, you have to call `await`